# How to go to the last pagination page in CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp, pagination, cakephp-3.0

In CakePHP 1.3 I could go to the last pagination page by adding the parameter `page:last`.

I tried to use `?page=last` in CakePHP 3.0 but it does not work. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

The functionality you mention was removed in CakePHP 2.0.

In CakePHP 3.x, to create a link from within the view, you can call

```
$this->Paginator->last($last = 'last >>', $options =[])
```

To obtain the last page from within a controller, you can access the following property:

```
$this->request->params['paging']['pageCount']
```

**EDIT**

A possible workaround to accept `page:last` would be to add the following at the beginning of your action:

```
public function index() {
    // detect page:last
    if (!empty($this->request->params['named']['page'] && @$this->request->params['named']['page']=='last')) {
        $this->Paginator->paginate();
        $this->request->params['named']['page']=$this->request['paging'][$this->modelClass]['pageCount'];
    }

    //rest of code for action

    $this->set('results', $this->Paginator->paginate());
}
```

You have to call `$this->paginate()` twice, so it's not ideal.

---

Another option is perhaps to extend `lib/Cake/Controller/Component/PaginatorComponent.php` so that it supports `page:last`. For further information, see

- [Paginator (Migration from Cake 1.3 to 2.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515913/paginator-migration-from-cake-1-3-to-2-0#15390753)

Comment: Thanks for answer. But how can I directly go to the last page of pagination from other controller? It seems that i have to go to controller with pagination calculate the last page and then redirect to the same controller on the last page - it does not seem to be elegant solution.

Comment: It's not too elegant, I agree. See the last part of my answer.